# wrap() method and child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

When I do this:

```
myUl = $(document.createElement("ul"));
myLi = $(document.createElement("li"));
myUl.append(myLi);
```

The myLi becomes a child element of myUl. This is good.

When I do this:

```
myUl = $(document.createElement("ul"));
myLi = $(document.createElement("li"));
myLi.wrap(myUl);
```

Then myUl has 0 child elements, even though the DOM looks the same. Is this normal?

Comment: btw, you can do `$('<ul>')` to create the `ul` element. If you're using jQuery anyways, why not go the full extent with it.

Comment: Complete solution:    
    `var Ul = $('<ul>'); 
    $('#originalLI').parent().append(Ul); 
    $('#originalLI').appendTo(Ul);`

Answer (score 1):

`.wrap` is working with a clone of `myUl`, instead of the original like `.append` does.

This makes sense when you consider that calling `.wrap` on a jQuery object with multiple elements will wrap each element in a separate copy of whatever you passed.

**UPDATE:** From your other comments, I think what you want to do is this:

```
myLi = $(document.createElement("li"));
myLi.wrap('<ul>');
```

This (or some code like it) will wrap an existing element with a new UL created on the fly.

Comment: No, the HTML is identical. The DOM element is different.

Comment: So how can I get around this?

Comment: `.append` your inner element to the outer element instead, like you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.createElement`, you can just use `$("<ul>")`... so for example:

`$("<li>").wrap($("<ul>"));`

I would go this approach instead of trying to wrap your `myLi` in the existing `myUl` object like so...

```
var $li = $("<li>");

//added class for another short-hand example
$("<ul class='myClass'>").append($li);
```

Let's say you have an existing element on the page and you want to wrap it in a freshly created JS Object...

```
var $ul = $("<ul>");  
$('#myLi').appendTo($ul)

//and if you want to clone it
$('#myLi').clone().appendTo($ul)
```

Comment: Yeah but I can't do that. I have an element that's already on the page (the <li> in the example) and I want to wrap that with something I create on the fly (the <ul> in the example)...

Comment: See my updated response.  I believe you need `appendTo()` to actually move it from the DOM into your object.  `wrap()` I believe it just for creating new objects and wrapping adhoc...

Comment: I'll take upvotes and answers I'm not picky but I do dream of green checkmarks for some odd reasons...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> "The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be
>   passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This
>   structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only
>   one inmost element."

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Are you wrapping more than one `<li>`?

Comment: No just one. One <li> inside an <ul> and it doesn't find any children.